# How to unzip the zip attachment from email using Lumisoft.net

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Lumisoft for process file attached in an email.
Suppose if there is .txt or .pdf as attachment in email then I can process it
But is it possible to process on Zip attachment.

I mean I want to extract zip and process on file(.rpt).

Is this possible using Lumisoft.net

Answer (score 1):

Once you have retrieved the zipped attachment using Lumisoft you could use the .net 4.5 System.IO.Compression to unzip it and then process it as you usually do.

This is a simplified snippet from a project I am currently working on:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
          // filter archive content if necessary
          if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".csv", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
          {
                var extractPath = Path.Combine("Attachments", entry.FullName);
                entry.ExtractToFile(extractPath, true);

                // Process file
                DoSomethingWithTheFile(extractPath);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: This process  can be done once file get unzipped. But my question is how to unzip the zip attachment

Comment: The line entry.ExtractToFile does extract whatever is in the zip file. You are passing the "filePath" to a zip file. I am not sure what you are asking if that is not a solution. Could you elaborate a bit maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Go [Here](http://www.lumisoft.ee/Forum/yaf_postst612_Extract-Eml-from-email-attachment.aspx), there is a good example of extracting an eml file, The logic is the same for what you want to do.

Comment: Ya, this code is for simple attachment and not for Zip